# How to set the data in local storage for multiple users in angular js 1?

Tags: angularjs, local-storage

```
service.setState = function (sessionObj, user) {
    $localStorage.sessions = {
        sessionObj: sessionObj,
        user: user
    };

}

service.getState = function (user) {
    return $localStorage.sessions;
}
```

I am using this, but it only save the current state. when i login from the other id it returns me the same local storage state data. What I want is different saved states data for different users.

Comment: use sessionStorage instead localStorage

Comment: @Tuhin I want to keep the data store. Scenario is if i login with user 1 i got the data for user 1 and if i login from user 2 i got the data of user 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   service.addState = function(sessionObj, user) {
       if($localStorage.sessions === undefined || $localStorage.sessions=="null"){
           $localStorage.sessions = angular.toJson({});
       }
       var sessions = angular.fromJson($localStorage.sessions);
       sessions[user] = sessionObj;
       $localStorage.sessions = angular.toJson(sessions);
    }

    service.getState = function(user) {
        var sessions = angular.fromJson($localStorage.sessions);
        return sessions[user];
    }
```

Here your localStorage structure will be:

```
sessions :{
 user1:sessionObj1,
 user2:sessionObj2,
.....
}
```

used toJson and fromJson as localStorage and sessionStorage only work with String.

Comment: Thank you so much, perfectly working for me according to my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You should not store the session in local Storage. Use the Session Storage instead.

In case you need this to be working somehow then define it as an array of objects.

```
var users= [{
                sessionObj: sessionObj1,
                user: user1
            },
          {
                sessionObj: sessionObj2,
                user: user2
            }];

localStorage.setItem("userSessions", JSON.stringify(users));
```

You need to push session for each user

Answer (score 0):

You cannot save JSON data to a local storage variable, You have to stringify the JSON frist before saving to localstorage.

```
var Data = {
    sessionObj: sessionObj,
    user: user
};

$localStorage.sessions = JSON.stringify(Data);
```

and on retriving the data, parse the localstorage value.

```
var Response = JSON.parse($localStorage.sessions);
```